# Making Recursive Feature Elimination using Caret parallel on Windows

Tags: r, parallel-processing, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I'm trying to run recursive feature elimination for a random forest on a data frame containing 27 predictor variables, each with 3653 values. So there's 98631 values total in the predictor dataframe. I'm using the *rfe* function from the package *caret*.

```
require(caret)
require(randomForest)

subsets <- c(1:5, 10, 15, 20, 25)

set.seed(10)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                   method = "repeatedcv",
                   repeats = 5,
                   verbose = FALSE,
                   allowParallel=TRUE)

rfProfile <- rfe(predictors, 
                 y,
                 sizes = subsets,
                 rfeControl = ctrl)
```

I'm using *allowParallel=TRUE* in *rfeControl*, hoping that it will run the process in parallel on my Windows machine. But I'm not sure if it's doing that, since I do not see any decrease in run time after setting *allowParallel=TRUE*. The process takes a very long time, and I've had to interrupt the kernal after 1-2 hours each time.

How do I know if *caret* is running the RFE in parallel? Do I need to install any other parallelization packages for *caret* to run this process in parallel?

Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated! I'm new to the machine learning world, so it's taking me a while to figure things out.

Comment: Not a caret user, but I guess the implementation use forking which is not supported by windows. For your size of data set that should take few minutes unless also coupled with parameter tuning. A stand-alone-function using foreach and doParallel (supported by windows) could be written in ~25 lines

Comment: I must say, without any intent to contribute a meaningful response, that your question title was very intriguing. (And I have a nagging fear that pkg:caret is a disguised multiple comparisons engine.)

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can always pull up task manager and see if all of your processors are actually working. I don't think this is a robust solution, but it at least gives you an idea.

Comment: Thank you, @SorenH.Welling. I'm a R newbie, so the task of writing parallel code seems slightly daunting. But I will give it a go sometime soon!

Comment: @BondedDust Again, not adding anything to the response, might I ask you what a multiple comparison engine is? I tried searching for the meaning, but couldn't find a reliable description.

Comment: I was worried that people may be unwittingly using 'caret' to generate spurious conclusions, unless there is adequate correction for the large number of hypotheses being tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing and registering the `doParallel` package prior to running `rfe`.  This seemed to work on my Windows machine.

Here's a lengthy example pulled from the `caret` documentation with timing before and after using `doParallel`

```
subsetSizes <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
set.seed(123)
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 51)
for(i in 1:50) seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, length(subsetSizes) + 1)
seeds[[51]] <- sample.int(1000, 1)

data(BloodBrain)
```

Run without parallel processing

```
set.seed(1)
system.time(rfMod <- rfe(bbbDescr, logBBB,
         sizes = subsetSizes,
         rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, 
                                 seeds = seeds,
                                 number = 50)))

   user  system elapsed 
 113.32    0.44  114.43
```

Register parallel

```
library(doParallel) 
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type='PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

Run with parallel processing

```
set.seed(1)
system.time(rfMod <- rfe(bbbDescr, logBBB,
         sizes = subsetSizes,
         rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, 
                                 seeds = seeds,
                                 number = 50)))

   user  system elapsed 
   1.57    0.01   56.27
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Could you please explain why you are declaring a 'seeds' variable separately? It is different than the set.seed() parameter?

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad this helped.  I took this example straight from `?rfe`, so this example is not my original code.  I just used it to test parallel processing.  `seeds=` is different from `set.seed()`.  `set.seed()` is a function to set the state for the random number generator.  `seeds` is a parameter for the `caret::rfe` function

Comment: `seeds` it is not specific for `rfeControl()`, it is also available for `trainControl()`, `gafsControl()`, etc. It is used to set the seed at each resampling iteration. This is useful when the models are run in parallel. By doing this, the same results can be reproduced when you run the same code several times (reproducible research).